# Directions API - Destination with stopover side

Tags: google-directions-api

I'm currently ordering locations to draw a route with waypoints using the Directions API for deliveries. This works very well.

I was wondering however if there was any way to draw the routes so that all waypoints would be on the drivers right side. Since we are delivering goods, this is a safty hazard when we arrive from across the street.

thanks for anyhelp

Answer (score 0):

This is currently an intended behavior for the Directions API to have the waypoint/destination to be on the most accessible side along the way -- right side of the vehicle for most countries or on the left side for countries like England.

If this is not the case for you however, you can file a feature request in the Google's Public Issue Tracker [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#issue_tracker) providing your specific use-case and samples.

Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development.